# Stop event propogation from DOM elements created dynamically via a library

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, smart-table

I'm using AngularJS 1.7.5, x-editable, and smart table.  Inside of a table row I have an anchor which opens a select via x-editable. I am also enabling row selection in smart table.

The problem is that I am unsure of how to stop the click event from the select from  propogating and selecting or deselecting the table row. I have written a directive to suppress the click from the A element which opens the select, but the select is created by the x-editable library (e.g. not in my HTML.)

https://plnkr.co/edit/kAKbgLg05uBA9etICxV7?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.7.0" data-semver="1.7.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-smart-table/2.1.8/smart-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script data-require="xeditable@*" data-semver="0.1.8" src="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.7" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController as $ctrl">
  <table st-table="collection" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Secret Identity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in collection" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple">
        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" editable-select="row.secretIdentity" data-value="{{ row.secretIdentity }}" class="editable editable-click" buttons="no" mode="inline" e-ng-options="i for i in options" stop-event="click">
                {{ row.secretIdentity }}
               </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['xeditable', 'smart-table', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', 'editableOptions', function($scope, editableOptions) {
    editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';

    $scope.collection = [{
      name: 'Ed',
      id: 1,
      secretIdentity: 'Just some guy'
    }, {
      name: 'Tony',
      id: 2,
      secretIdentity: 'Iron Man'
    }, {
      name: 'Steve',
      id: 3,
      secretIdentity: 'Captain America'
    }, {
      name: 'Bruce',
      id: 4,
      secretIdentity: 'Hulk'
    }, {
      name: 'Clint',
      id: 5,
      secretIdentity: 'Hawkeye'
    }, {
      name: 'Natasha',
      id: 6,
      secretIdentity: 'Black Widow'
    }, ];

    $scope.options = ['Iron Man', 'Captain America', 'Hulk', 'Black Widow', 'Hawkeye', 'Just some guy'];
  }])
```

```
  .directive('stopEvent', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope, element, attr) => {
        if (attr && attr.stopEvent) {
          element.bind(attr.stopEvent, e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          });
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

Is there a standard way for manipulating elements created by x-editable which will also play nice with AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `<a>` in a `<div>` and add your `stop-event` directive to that div.

```
<td>
  <div stop-event="click">
     <a href="#" 
         editable-select="row.secretIdentity" 
         data-value="{{ row.secretIdentity }}" 
         class="editable editable-click" 
         buttons="no" 
         mode="inline"
         e-ng-options="i for i in options"
      >
         {{ row.secretIdentity }}
      </a>
  </div>
</td>
```